Expo Video Player Audio Overlap Issue When Pushing Video Screens on top of each other
I'm experiencing an audio overlap/reverb issue in my React Native Expo app when navigating through screens containing video players. The issue specifically occurs when navigating from a video screen to another screen and then to another video screen, with all of the screens being pushed on top of each other by expo router.
When a user navigates:

Video Screen A -> plays fine ->Next (Pushes another screen)
Another Screen -> no video content -> Next (Pushes a video screen)
Video Screen B -> audio from Video Instance A overlaps with Video Instance B, creating an echo/reverb effect

Both of the video instances play the same audio, so the URI corresponding to video screen A is set to the URI corresponding to Video Screen B somehow.
Interestingly, this issue only occurs in this specific navigation pattern. Direct navigation between video screens (Video A -> Video B) works perfectly fine with no audio overlap
My implementations of the video player component:
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback, useContext } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Dimensions, Image, Platform } from "react-native";
import { Video, ResizeMode, AVPlaybackStatus, Audio } from "expo-av";
import { useFocusEffect } from "expo-router";
//more imports 

const { width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");

//Unique video id just for logging purposes
const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const instanceId = useRef(`video-${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}`).current;

  const videoRef = useRef<Video | null>(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<AVPlaybackStatus | {}>({});


    // Cleanup function to stop video and release resources
    const cleanupVideo = async () => {
      if (videoRef.current) {
        try {
          await videoRef.current.stopAsync();
          await videoRef.current.unloadAsync();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(`[${instanceId}] Error during cleanup:`, error);
        }
      }
    };

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      console.log(`[${instanceId}] Screen focused - hasEnded: ${hasEnded}`);
      console.log(`[${instanceId}] Current video state - isPlaying: ${isPlaying}, isLoading: ${isLoading}`);
      return async () => {
          setCompleteVideo(false);
          progressAnim.setValue(0);
          if (videoRef.current) {
            await videoRef.current.setPositionAsync(0);
          }
          setCurrentTime(0);
          setHasEnded(false);
      }
    }, [])
  );

  const currentSection = courseData?.sections[currentSectionIndex];
  const hasVideoDescription = currentSection?.section_video_description?.description;


  useEffect(() => {
    // Cleanup function to clear the timer when component unmounts
    return () => {
      cleanupVideo();
      if (controlsTimer.current) {
        clearTimeout(controlsTimer.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);



  const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = useCallback(async (newStatus: AVPlaybackStatus) => {
    setStatus(newStatus);

    if (!newStatus.isLoaded) {
      setIsLoading(true);
    } else if (newStatus.isLoaded) {
      
      if (newStatus.isBuffering) {
        setIsLoading(true)
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(`[${instanceId}] Current video state - isPlaying: ${isPlaying}`);
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ playsInSilentModeIOS: true });
        }
      }
      if (newStatus.didJustFinish) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setHasEnded(true);
        setCompleteVideo(true);
        setIsPlaying(false);
      }
    }
  }, []);


  return (
          //Surrounding JSX

          <Video
            ref={videoRef}
            source={{ uri: currentSection.section_video_link || "" }}
            style={styles.video}
            shouldPlay
            resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
            useNativeControls
          />

          //Surrounding JSX
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ///Styles
});

export default VideoPlayer;

Here are the logs for going from "Video A -> Another Screen -> Video B":
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Screen focused - hasEnded: false
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Current video state - isPlaying: true, isLoading: false
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 //A bunch of 'isPlaying: true' logs

 //Navigates to a new screen
 //New Screen logs
 LOG  Moving to next video screen
 LOG  [video-2w8kpies8] Screen focused - hasEnded: false
 LOG  [video-2w8kpies8] Current video state - isPlaying: true, isLoading: false
 LOG  [video-2w8kpies8] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-2w8kpies8] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-2w8kpies8] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-3ulp5r2ir] Current video state - isPlaying: true
//As you can see here, both of the videos play overlapping one another
//They play the same video as well, so they have the same URI source after navigating to Video B


Here are the logs for going from "Video A -> Video B":
LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Screen focused - hasEnded: false
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true, isLoading: false
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 // Bunch of logs saying the video is playing
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
// Navigate to video screen B

 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Screen focused - hasEnded: false
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true, isLoading: false
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-eec8or6ja] Current video state - isPlaying: true
//Transient logs saying the previous video instance is playing, but 
//stop showing once the other video instance starts playing
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
//Bunch of logs saying only video B is playing now
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
 LOG  [video-hmnb8icow] Current video state - isPlaying: true
.....

Not sure why this is the case, I suspect it is an issue with the useRef not being cleaned up properly? But I am new to the react native ecosystem so any help is welcome.
